# Unknown predicate error in "find" command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

I am trying to find all files having names ending with the `~` character like this:

`find /path/to/my/folder -type f -name="*~"`

However, I am getting the error: `find: unknown predicate '-name=*~'`

Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a space () instead off the `=` between `-name` and the `"*~"`;

```sh
find /path/to/my/folder -type f -name "*~"
```

Read more about `-name` at [the Man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).